# pywinauto - How to select menu item? (uia backend)

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a Qt application, with a button, which on clicking will open a menu. How can I select a menu item from that menu pop up.

**What I have done so far?**

- I am able to select the button and click it
- `dump_tree` after pop up is open
- But I don't see any reference to menu pop up

How to proceed?

P.S. 
The menu is added programatically, i.e. Create QMenu and add menu to the button. I have set accessible name to the QMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience Qt seems to create the menu without parent window, no matter what I do. Then starting the search from the desktop worked for me:

```
menu = pywinauto.Desktop(backend='uia').window(class_name='QMenu')
menu.dump_tree()
```